# Simple practical example for two way data binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can any one help me out to understand what exactly two way data binding in AngularJS means with a help of simple code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425052/how-angularjs-implement-its-two-way-data-binding-mechanism/30425085#30425085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way data binding** -

The model values are automatically assigned to the HTML placeholder elements specified through the data binding notation, but **the HTML elements don't change the values in the model(one way)**.

**Example** :

*Controller* :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.firstName = 'John'; 
});
```

*HTML* :

```
<span>First name:</span> {{firstName}}<br />
```

**Two Way Data Binding** -

The model values are automatically assigned to the HTML placeholder elements specified through the data binding notation, where **HTML elements can change the value in the model(two way)**.

**Example** :

*Controller* :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.firstName = 'John'; 
});
```

*HTML*

```
<span>First name:</span> {{firstName}}<br />
<span>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/></span><br />
```

In above example we can change firstName model value with the help of HTML  Input element.

Working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/GxqBiOoNFuECn55R4uJZ?p=preview

Comment: In this example when model changes ie when "$scope.firstName" changes HTML also changes , if my understanding is not wrong. If that is the case then the label "First name:" should be "John" on page load . Right??. Please correct me if I am wrong. Actually I am trying to understand the concept of "when model changes view also changes".

Comment: Yes. Its right. In first example when we update $scope.firstName value from controller then only its changed value in HTML(so one way). But in second case we can change it from controller as well as from HTML(i.e view) so it is (two way).

Comment: Okay...But when I ran the below code in browser it is not showing First name as "John" on page load. Why it so.<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.firstName = 'John';    
  });
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
  <span>First name:</span> {{firstName}}<br />
  <span>Set the first name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/></span><br />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Please check this working example http://plnkr.co/edit/GxqBiOoNFuECn55R4uJZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Retrieved from the [AngularJS homepage](https://angularjs.org/#the-basics) (2015.06.02):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is possibly the simplest example of two-way data binding in Angular.
The `<input>` is associated to a `yourName` *model*, and the same *model* is used to fill the content of the `<h1>` tag. Modifying one will automatically update the other.

Although the data binding in the example can be seen as *one-way*, because you can't modify the `<h1>` directly, this should get you started. The AngularJS docs and tutorials contain a lot of great resources.