# Does Two Way Data Binding in Angular work same as AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, two-way-binding

Implementation of two way data binding in Angular 2 is same as AngularJs as described in below link or is it event based? I just want to decide whether to go with angular or not based on this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30425085/2792959

Is angular 2 also based on digest cycle?

Comment: This may help you - http://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: @SumitM. Thanks. So there isn't digest cycle but all event detection. But still it compares for all components. So still performance issue can be there for large application with more components, right?